# How to reuse array schema with SimpleSchema

Tags: node.js, meteor, geojson, simple-schema

I'm trying to define the GeoJSON schema in `node-simple-schema` to use in my application.

I'm trying to define the position, linestring, linering and polygon arrays to use them later when defining the Point, LineString,.. geometries.

This is what I'm doing now, and it does not work.

```
const Position = new SimpleSchema({
  position: {
    type: Array,
    label: 'A single position. ...',
    minCount: 2,
    maxCount: 3,
  },
  'position.$': {
    type: Number,
    label: 'A number representing...',
  },
});

const Point = new SimpleSchema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    label: 'The type of the feature.',
    allowedValues: ['Point'],
  },
  coordinates: {
    type: Position.pick('position'),
    // this does not work either
    // type: Position.getObjectSchema('position'),
    label: 'A single position',
  },
});
```

When I try to validate like this I get an error.

```
const PointExample = {
  type: 'Point',
  coordinates: [180.0, 46.5, 100],
};

Point.validate(PointExample);
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracted schemas matches objects with both keys and values. Therefore the following provided the key 'position' validates.

```
const PointExample = {
  type: 'Point',
  coordinates: {
    position: [180.0, 46.5, 100] // This is what matches the 'Position' schema.
  }
};

Point.validate(PointExample);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that is the Schema that gets defined and not the one I actually want.
If you understand what I want to achieve, do you know a way to get the Schema I want?